# How can I open in the Adobe Reader application("AcroRd32.exe"), a PDF online with url?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, adobe

So my problem is I'm trying to open a PDF file to sign the document, but the document only exists online. To sign the PDF I would like to click in a Button and it would open the PDF that i want, but in the Adobe Reader application. So that the user could do whatever he wants in the PDF.

Need some help on the part of open a pdf that only exists online, but in the application od the adobe Reader.

Thanks any help!!

**EDIT1:**

So the problem is that my boss do not want the PDF to be download. He wants to click the button and open in the Adobe Reader Application...

Comment: Tell your boss that technically, anything you read in a browser it is downloaded. I know what he means.  But to sign a PDF it has to be saved, which is has to be saved local on the computer hard drive.  Then you can upload the signed document back up to your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to open the file from AdobeReader locally, you are going to have to copy at minimum a temp file locally. Otherwise, you would have to either create or use a web application that is capable of accessing these files. Either way whatever is accessing the PDF is going to need a copy to display whether it's on your local machine or on a server somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Any PDF that exists online can be downloaded. Once downloaded, you can open it in any PDF reader like AdobeReader. Are you sure you are not able to download it?

Comment: So the problem is that my boss do not want the PDF to be download. He wants to click the button and open in the Adobe Reader Application...